# HAproxy- Could not open configuration file: Permission denied

Tags: configuration, haproxy

I am having some test with HAproxy as Load Balancer. I installed it and configured too, even the log with rsyslog. I checked the configuration with  `haproxy -c -f /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cnf` and with `haproxy -d -f /etc/haproxy.cnf`. All seem to be fine, but after starting haproxy, `systemctl start haproxy`, I executed `systemctl status haproxy`, it showed me this:

```
haproxy.service - HAProxy Load Balancer
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/haproxy.service; enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since jue 2015-07-02 14:47:13 CDT; 7s ago
  Process: 29832 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/haproxy-systemd-wrapper -f /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg -p /run/haproxy.pid (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 29832 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
systemd[1]: Started HAProxy Load Balancer.
haproxy-systemd-wrapper[29832]: haproxy-systemd-wrapper: executing /usr/sbin/haproxy -f /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg -p /run/haproxy.pid -Ds
haproxy-systemd-wrapper[29832]: [ALERT] 182/144713 (29833) : Could not open configuration file /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg : Permission denied
haproxy-systemd-wrapper[29832]: haproxy-systemd-wrapper: exit, haproxy RC=256
```

Logically this must point to file permissions, so I had 777 permissions to haproxy.cnf with the same result. I test chown haproxy:haproxy, same result.

I had goggle a lot, but I don't find a solution to that problem.

Comment: Don't _ever_ do 777 permissions on _anything_. This is a very bad habit to get into and will only cause you grief.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe there is some misconfiguration on Selinux(if you are using a Redhat based distribution) or on apparmor(if you are using ubuntu).

Try to stop them in order to verify if this is the problem.
You can also try to read the configuration file using the user running the haproxy daemon using the command:

`sudo -u <haproxy_user> cat /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg`

Comment: In fact the problem is Selinux. After exec on shell `semanage permissive -a haproxy_t` all fine. Thanks for the answers. For more information about selinux and haproxy: [https://www.mankier.com/8/haproxy_selinux]

Comment: Don't disable SELinux. Fix the context on the file instead.